# I can`t disable user in Dynamics365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365

Could you please help my? User on Dynamics365 still enabled after remove license and remove this user with the group Global Admins Office365.
Thanks.

Comment: It should replicate & may take some time, try giving license again & revoke it. Is this happening for any particular user account? Did you test with some other user account?

Answer (score 1):

Give it some time. The synchronization is not live. I can guarantee you Microsoft won't let you have an active user without a licence.